# parameters not being passed in to api controller from $http.post

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

**AngularJS:**

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"]= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:17438/api/people/PostPerson/',
    method: "POST",
    data: { name: vm.parent[i].name, dob: '01/15/2001', email: vm.parent[i].email, phone: vm.parent[i].cell, carrierName: vm.parent[i].carrier, personTypeID: 1 }
})
.then(function (response) {
    // success
    alert('sucess : ' + response);
},
function (response) { // optional
    // failed
    alert('failure : ' + response);
});
```

I've also tried this variation:

```
var data = { name: vm.parent[i].name, dob: '01/15/2001', email: vm.parent[i].email, phone: vm.parent[i].cell, carrierName: vm.parent[i].carrier, personTypeID: 1 };
$http.post('http://localhost:17438/api/people/PostPerson/', data);
```

**Parameters being passed:**

```
{"name":"jv","dob":"01/15/2001","email":"j@live.com","phone":"5551212","carrierName":"Sprint","personTypeID":1}:
```

**webAPI:**

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpOptions]
public string PostPerson(newUserRegistration newReg)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(0);
    person myPerson = new person();
    myPerson.personName = newReg.name;
    myPerson.personEmail = newReg.email;
    myPerson.personPhone = newReg.phone;
    myPerson.personPhoneCarrier = newReg.carrierName;
    myPerson.personDOB = newReg.dob;
    myPerson.familyID = newReg.familyID;
    myPerson.personTypeID = newReg.personTypeID;

    db.people.Add(myPerson);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return "got here";
}

public class newUserRegistration
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string carrierName { get; set; }
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    public string registrationID { get; set; }
    public int familyID { get; set; }

    public int personTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

**Parameter population:**

I know it is hard to read but you can see the values I'm passing in are NOT being passed into my `newUserRegistration` object

[image]

I've looked at several questions on Stack that seems to reference this type of issue.

[Angular POST to Web API doesn't pass data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925540/angular-post-to-web-api-doesnt-pass-data)

[issue in Angularjs $http.post to webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924473/issue-in-angularjs-http-post-to-webapi)

This project is currently using 1.3.15 - I'm not sure if upgrading to 1.5 help?

What am I missing on this?

**UPDATE:**

There was a comment that is now gone, but I stringified the data as suggested:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ name: vm.parent[i].name, dob: '01/15/2001', email: vm.parent[i].email, phone: vm.parent[i].cell, carrierName: vm.parent[i].carrier, personTypeID: 1 });

$http.post('http://localhost:17438/api/people/PostPerson/', data);
```

I noticed something strange though.  It is calling the API method 2 times, the 1st time has null data (as witnessed originally), but it calls it a 2nd time and the data is there!

I'm not sure why it is being called twice though?  Is there anything I'm doing incorrectly now that I'm stringifying the data?

**Update to double call:**

I noticed the following:
[image]

You will notice one says OPTIONS and the other says POST.  Now the webAPI also has the following tags:

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpOptions]
```

If I removed the Options, it fails (can't find 404).  Do these tags have something to do with this?

Comment: Check your code to make sure you are not sending it twice. Easy to overlook while you were troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi - I updated my question.  Any ideas?

Comment: Checking, but it looks like it has something to do with CORS

Comment: was the http options there by default or was it added manually by you?

Comment: @Nkosi - I must have added.  I don't know why, and I don't know what it does.  I just know when I take it off, I'm getting a 404 error.

Comment: Angular may be doing a prefetch and since removing the options causes that to 404 it does not perform the actual call. I am not that versed in angularjs to cannot say for certain. as a work around keep the httpoptions and in the action add a condition to for when the model state is valid. add validation attributes to the model.

Comment: yes I think this is a CORs issues now.  However, when I start to do some of the suggestions to "fix" the issue it breaks everything :(  - It seems that the 1st run through with NULL is something called the "preflight".

Comment: yes `preflight` was what i meant to say.

Comment: @Nkosi - I think it is more of a webAPI issue then an Angular issue.

Comment: Are the hosts for the angular site and the api site different? For example the api is http://localhost:17438 and the angular site is 'http://localhost:17499

Comment: @KentCooper - yes

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to wrap your json

```
var url = 'http://localhost:17438/api/people/PostPerson/';
var data = JSON.stringify({ name: vm.parent[i].name, dob: '01/15/2001', email: vm.parent[i].email, phone: vm.parent[i].cell, carrierName: vm.parent[i].carrier, personTypeID: 1 });
$http.post(url, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're finding out, this is a web server issue more than an Angular one.

If your angular app is delivered on the same server:port as your service endpoints, try using a relative hyperlink and see if the OPTIONS request disappears. The presence of the domain name in a XmlHttpRequest for the application/json content-type is usually enough to trigger the CORS check.

I will say that I've seen this much more frequently when connecting to IIS, but it's not exclusive. A lot depends on the underlying server config. The OPTIONS request is like the handshake for SSL: the angular request is trying to figure out what the system will allow, then sending the payload once permissions are granted.

[MDN - Access Control with CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"]= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

You are telling the api server you are going to send it a form encoded body and you are instead sending it a JSON body and so when the api server goes to parse the body of the request it is null.

NOTE: If you are using Asp.Net Web Api's built in OAuth provider then you will need to post to the /token method using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded data type but for all other calls you can use JSON.

As for the duplicate requests that is caused by your browser making a CORS check. That is perfectly normal if your API hostname is different from you angular hostname.